# Why I can't change element of the array in forEach()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach

Here's my function. It's supposed to return `backgroundColor` instead of `backgroundcolor`.

What's my problem?

```js
function camelize(str) {
  let newStr = str.split('-');
  newStr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      item.toLowerCase();
      item = item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
    }
  });

  newStr = newStr.join('');
  return newStr;
}
console.log(camelize("background-color")); //'backgroundсolor' instead of 'backgroundColor'
```

Comment: Well your code was full of weirdness. I had to add () => and remove some newlines and add a ); Secondly you never save or return any of the changes

Comment: Assigning to the local variable doesn't change the original array.

Comment: strings are immutable, and forEach doesn't return; change one of those things. hint: assign `newStr[index]` instead of item.

Comment: `const camelize = str => str.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, ' ').replace(/\s+([a-z])/g, $1 => $1.toUpperCase()).replace(/ /g, '')` trim it, lowercase it all, replace - with space, replace letters after space with cap version, remove spaces

Comment: @Barmar it looks like only objects or arrays can be assigned by the link. But it's not about their properties or elements. They are just copied. There's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/pt27snw4/). Am I right?

Comment: Correct. JavaScript doesn't have references to array elements and object properties.

Comment: @Heaven Please return and interact with the people who spent time answering your question

Answer (score 5):

1. You need a map
2. you need to return the item

I simplified the code

```js
const camelize = str => str
  .toLowerCase()
  .split('-').map((item, index) => index > 0 ? 
      item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1) : item)
  .join('');

console.log(camelize("background-color")); 
console.log(camelize("Background-color")); 
console.log(camelize("BACKGROUND-COLOR"));
```

Closer to your old code

```js
function camelize(str) {
  const parts = str.toLowerCase().split('-');
  let newStr = parts.map((item, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      item = item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
    }
    return item
  });

  newStr = newStr.join('');
  return newStr;
}
console.log(camelize("background-color"));
```

Comment: One suggestion. Move the `item.toLowerCase()` outside the `if` statement so that the first word is always lowercased. Otherwise the function would break with this input `Background-color`.

Comment: If I may make one more suggestion, remove the else and place the `item = item.toLowerCase();` at the top of the map iteration function. This should catch the final edge case of `Background-COLOR` which would still fail in this case. Sorry, not trying to nitpick just helping to form a fool-proof solution for any combination of casing.

Comment: @War10ck Ok, done

Comment: Nice! Hadn't thought of including it before map. That's elegant. +1

Comment: @War10ck and cut it some more :)

Comment: That's rockstar status buddy!

Answer (score 4):

`item` is a local variable inside the function. Assigning to it has no effect on `newStr`.

`item.toLowerCase()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the string in place (JS strings are immutable). You need to assign it back to the variable to change it.

Use `map()` instead of `forEach()` so you return a new array with the results.

```js
function camelize(str) {
  let oldStr = str.split('-');
  let newStr = oldStr.map((item, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      item = item.toLowerCase();
      item = item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
    }
    return item;
  });

  return newStr.join('');
}
console.log(camelize("background-color")); //'backgroundсolor' instead of 'backgroundColor'
```

Comment: One suggestion. Move the `item.toLowerCase()` outside the `if` statement so that the first word is always lowercased. Otherwise the function would break with this input `Background-color`.